# Sizing a Flex DataGrid to fit the data, then scrolling

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, scroll

I have a UI that is a master/details UI design pattern. There is a DataGrid that holds 1-n records in the top part section of a VDividedBox, then a details pane in the bottom part that shows details of the record selected in the DataGrid, responding to the selection.

The DataGrid usually only contains a small number of items, and so I'd like in most cases for the DataGrid to size to the number of rows and for the details pane to be shown just below the table with no empty space or empty rows. I've got that working OK by setting rowCount="{tableData.length}", where tableData is the data provider. So far, so good.

However, occasionally the table contains a larger number of items, and in these cases I'd like the table to grow to fill the available space, then scroll when there are too many items to show, without the details pane scrolling off. That is, behave like the rowCount is not set to the dataprovider length, and the height set to 100%.

My problem is, determining when to make this switch. What is the best way to switch the behavior from the rowCount-based height, to the percentage based height? Or am I missing some trick that would make the rowCount-based height table scroll when it runs out of space?

Thanks,

Paddy

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the rowCount via:

```
rowCount="{tableData.length > 30 ? 30 : tableData.length }"
```

where 30 is the max height  you want to scale to?

That way if there are more than 30 (or some #) of rows it will scroll.